# C# Web API Quiero armar un JSON y recibirlo con en AngularJS 5/6

Tags: angularjs, api, web

Quiero armar un JSON desde el backend donde vendrán los textos según el idioma configurado por el usuario.

En el backend estoy usando una Web Api de .net y quiero tomar ese JSON en el frontend AngularJS 5/6 y de alguna manera poder usarlo no se si se posible almacenarlo en un fichero o si se puede usar como un objeto.

Tengo poca experiencia en AngularJS, actualmente el frontend maneja algunos JSON que esta físicamente en los archivos del proyecto del frontend.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que todo "AngularJS" es diferente a Angular. para las versiones de Angular2 y superiores solo es "Angular".

en el controlador de tu api puedes enviar el dato de esta forma

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCategory(int id)
    {
        var categoryModel = await _categoryService.FindCategoryModelById(id);
        if(categoryModel == null)
        {
            return new OkObjectResult(new
            {
                Message = "Categoria con id = " + id + " no existe",
                categoryModel
            });
        }
        return new OkObjectResult(new
        {
            categoryModel
        });
    }

public class CategoryModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Boolean State { get; set; } = true;
}
```

asume que _categoryService es un servicio que te trae una categoría definida

con angular con peticiones Get podrás recibir esta información como un json